# Primefaces datatable multiple selection row count

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, multipleselection

Firstly im sorry my english it is not my orginal language. I have a primefaces datatable and in multiple selection mode.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:panel>
    <p:tabView activeIndex="#{logoDocumentIntegration.tabIndex}" >
            <p:tab title="Aktarilmayan Musteriler">
                <p:dataTable id="notTransfaredClient"  rows="10" value="#{logoDocumentIntegration.notTransfaredClientList}" selection="#{logoDocumentIntegration.selectedTransfaredClientList}"  rowKey="#{cl.clientId}"  var="cl"  >
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>           
                    <p:column headerText="Id" style="width:2%" rendered="false">
                                <h:outputText value="#{cl.clientId}" /> 
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="TCNo" style="width:2%">
                                <h:outputText value="#{cl.taxNo}" />    
                            </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="İsim" style="width:2%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{cl.name}"  />    
                    </p:column>
<p:commandButton id="test" value="Ekle"  actionListener="#{logoDocumentIntegration.transferClient(logoDocumentIntegration.selectedTransfaredClientList)}"   />
```

I want to get selection row count from datatable.For this i used to a arraylist its name is selectedLis.In managedbean i have this line:

```
 private List<ClientView> selectedTransfaredClientList = new ArrayList<ClientView>();

public List<ClientView> getSelectedTransfaredClientList() {
    return selectedTransfaredClientList;
}

public void setSelectedTransfaredClientList(List<ClientView> selectedTransfaredClientList) {
    this.selectedTransfaredClientList = selectedTransfaredClientList;
}
```

Everything is okay but when i want to get selectedTransferedClientList count is returning 0.Where is my mistake thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: You do not seem to have implemented the PrimeFaces' data table row selection functionality properly. You  are referencing the list through a parameterized action method here `actionListener="#{logoDocumentIntegration.transferClient(logoDocumentIntegration.selectedTransfaredClientList)}"` which is not required. The list holding the selected rows is already available in the managed bean as long as it is at least a view scoped bean. The list may be empty, if the selected rows in the data table are not bound to the list in the associated managed bean either way for some unclear reasons.

Comment: Check out these examples on the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).